# Java errors in the Constructors

Tags: java, constructor

I receive a compilation error in my java program, but I can't understand what it is.

I have one main that executes four classes: `tower` (an organisation of `block`s), `block`, `coloredblock`, and `jollyblock`.

These are the errors:

```
.\coloredblock.java:8: error: constructor block in class block cannot be applied t
o given types;
    public coloredblock(int n,String c){
                                         ^

required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
.\coloredblock.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    if (c.lenght() > 10)
         ^
symbol:   method lenght()
location: variable c of type String
coloredblock.java:13: error: call to super must be first statement in constr
uctor
    super(n);
         ^
jollyblock.java:3: error: constructor block in class block cannot be applied to given    
    public jollyblock(int n){
```

This is the `block` class:

```
public abstract class block{
    //CAMPI
    private int number;
    private String color;

    public block(int n){
        if (n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n < 0!");
        number=n;
    }   
}
```

This is `coloredblock`:

```
public class coloredblock extends block{
    //CAMPI
    private String color;

    public coloredblock (int n,String c){
        if (n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n < 0!");
        if (c.lenght() > 10)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("more of 10!");
        super(n);
        color=c;
    }  
}
```

This is class `tower`:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tower{
    //CAMPI
    private String nametower;
    private ArrayList<Blocco> Towerblock;
    private int nblocchicolorati;
    private int nblocchijolly;

    public Torre(String n){     //COSTRUTTORI

        Towerblock= new ArrayList<block>();
        nametower=n;
    }

    public void addblock(block b){    //METODI
        Towerblock.add(0,b);  //da vedere
    }

    public int numColorati(){
        nblocchicolorati=0;

        for(int i=0;i < Towerblock.size();i++)
        {
            if(Towerblock.get(i) instanceof coloredblock)
            nblocchicolorati++;
        }

        return nblocchicolorati;
    }

    public int numJolly(){

        nblocchijolly=0;

        for(int i=0;i < Towerblock.size();i++)
        {
            if(Towerblock.get(i) instanceof jollyblock)
            nblocchicolorati++;
        }

        return nblocchijolly;

    }
}
```

//and this is the main:

```
public class exercise1{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Tower tower= new Tower ("Alfa");

        tower.addBlock( new coloredblock( 1, "green") );
        tower.addBlock( new coloredblock( 5, "green") );
        tower.addBlock( new coloredblock( 4, "red") );
        tower.addBlock( new jollyblock(10) );


        // *** Stampare tutta la torre
        //System.out.println("NUM. BLOCCHI COLORATI: " + tower.numColorati() );
        //System.out.println("NUM. BLOCCHI JOLLY: " + tower.numJolly() );
    } 
}
```

Thank you very very much for the help. This is an exercise I was given for a university course and tomorrow I will have an exam.

(I didn't include the code for `jollyblock` because it's similar to the code for `coloredblock`)

Comment: `lenght` is not `length`. Also, you can't call a super constructor except on the first line of a constructor.

Comment: wow thank you very much! :') i've passed all my afternoon for those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, please tell us what you have tried. And for these simple errors, try searching  Google and you will quickly find the answers.

Your call to "lenght" is not spelled right. It should be "length()".

The super(n) line should be the first line after the opening line of the constructor, like this:

```
public coloredblock (int n,String c){
    super(n); //first line
    if (n<0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n < 0!");
    if (c.lenght() > 10)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("more of 10!");
    color=c;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you i've searched those but i've a bad english and i don't understand much

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors. The first is that you misspelled the length() method. The other is that if you call super() in a constructor, it has to be the first statement in the constructor. Change your coloredblock constructor to something like:

```
public coloredblock (int n,String c) {
  super(n);

  if (n<0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("n < 0!");
  if (c.length() > 10)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("more of 10!");

  color=c;    
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!! ^^ now i've understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The super(n) command should be the first thing you call for an extended constructor. Also you do not need to repeat the same check 'if (n < 0)' because this was handled by the 'block' constructor. The 'super()' method executes all of the commands from the initial constructor. Try this and see if this fixes your issue:

```
public class coloredblock extends block
{

    //CAMPI

    private String color;

    public coloredblock (int n,String c)
    {

        super(n);

        if (c.lenght() > 10)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("more of 10!");

        color=c;    
    }
}
```